# Json string deserializing getting null in variable

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

When deserializing a json string, do you need to have a property set for every part of the string or why is the string not getting converted?

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString("https://omdb-api.now.sh/?i=tt7784604");
var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonMovies>(json);
return View(movies);

public class JsonMovies
{
        public IList<MovieData> movies { get; set; }
}

public class MovieData
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Getting a null reference for the var movies.

Comment: put an example of your JSON here.

Comment: Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieData>(json)` instead. The json represent an object, not a list of objects.

Comment: The Json data does not contain a property called `movies`. Hence you get the correct result. I.e. `null`. If you however change to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieData>(json)` you'd get the correct `title`.

Comment: Thank you Sani, you are totally right! Big blunder on my part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the `JSON` example from the [URL](http://%22https://omdb-api.now.sh/?i=tt7784604%22) you have provided.

This will be your C# Entities to catch the JSON:

```
public class Rating
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Rated { get; set; }
    public string Released { get; set; }
    public string Runtime { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string Actors { get; set; }
    public string Plot { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Awards { get; set; }
    public string Poster { get; set; }
    public List<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
    public string Metascore { get; set; }
    public string imdbRating { get; set; }
    public string imdbVotes { get; set; }
    public string imdbID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DVD { get; set; }
    public string BoxOffice { get; set; }
    public string Production { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

What you are going to do is that deserialize it base on this model.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var json = wc.DownloadString("https://omdb-api.now.sh/?i=tt7784604");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
    {
        var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        return View(movies);
    }
    //Json is null returns null to your view. 
    return View();
}
```

then you can be sure it's not null.